# Close view model (navigate back) in Init

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm attempting to call `Close(this)` in `Init` in a ViewModel to navigate back, but I'm receiving the following from Mvvmcross in the debug output when running on Android.

```
mvx:Warning:  7.59 Ignoring close for viewmodel - rootframe's current page is not the view for the requested viewmodel
```

Is it possible to `Close` here?

Maybe I'm approaching this wrong. I want to open a connection based on a `string` I'm passing in `Init` and if it fails, show a toast (or equivalent notification) and go back.

Comment: You might want to mention what platform this is for.

Comment: You can try to open the connection before going to the next view model. If it fails you show the toast. If it is ok then you open the ViewModel.

Comment: Couldn't you try ShowViewModel<PreviousView>()?  Perhaps add a parameter if needed.  Ideally you could do a check before you even go to the view model in the first place.

Comment: The idea is that there is a selection page and the next page actually makes the connection. This IConnection is registered as a type and not a singleton since I actually need multiple. Seems dirty to create an IConnection to test and then create another on the next view model. Is there way to pass non-primitive objects between view models?

Comment: In, lets call it SecondViewModel, calling ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel> works in Init works, but causes the back stack to include the SecondViewModel. This was why I was trying to call Close on the view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Nor can you do it in `Start`.